# Querying MongoDB nested array documents using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to implement the text search functionality with the nested array documents in MongoDB using C#. And I have a MongoDB collection in the below format.

```
{    
   "_id" : ObjectId("56c6f03ffd07dc1de805e84f"),
   "Customers" : {
            "Contact" : [ 
                           [
                             { 
                                "FirstName" : "Swetha", 
                                "LastName" : "DevAnand"
                             }
                           ]
                        ]
                   }
}
```

Mongo Query:

```
  db.test_collection.find({"Customers.Contact":{$elemMatch:{$elemMatch:{LastName: /.*Dev.*/}}}});
```

As in the above MongoDB query, I wanted to do a LIKE Search with the innermost array of BSON document using C#. However, I have acheived this using nested $elemMatch in Mongo Query. But while trying to do the same in C#, it expects the fieldname for every ElemMatch Query.In the above case, the innermost array of Contact field does not have any explicit field name. So far, I have tried all the below C# code to implement the scenario, but none of them helps.

```
var regex = new BsonRegularExpression(searchVal,"i");

query = Query.And(Query.ElemMatch("Customers.Contact", Query.And(Query.ElemMatch("LastName", Query.Matches("LastName", regex)))));
query = Query.And(Query.Matches("Customers.Contact.$.LastName",regex));
query = Query.And(Query.ElemMatch("Customers.Contact.$", Query.EQ("LastName", regex)));                 
query = Query.And(Query.ElemMatch("Customers.Contact.$", Query.Matches("LastName", regex)));
query = Query.And(Query.ElemMatch("Customers.Contact", Query.And(Query.ElemMatch("$", Query.EQ("LastName", regex)))));
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: SO isn't a code conversion service. Check Mongo C# driver docs and do it yourself

Comment: @Matias. Thanks for ur reply. I have gone through Mongo C# driver docs and it is of no help in this scenario, as in my MongoDB query i wanted to implement $elematch without specifying the fieldname of innermost array. And I am struggling to do the same in C#, where it expects the fieldname for every ElemMatch Query.Thus seeking for help in SO..

Comment: I believe you should explain your issue in the question's body instead of a comment. Your current text *as is* is just "please translate my code to C#" :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a week of struggle, found a way. The best method to implement the above MongoDB Query is to deserialize it into a BsonDocument which in return will be passed to FindAsync as filter.

```
var bQuery = "{'Customers.Contact':{$elemMatch:{$elemMatch:{LastName: /.*Dev.*/}}}}";
var filter = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(bQuery);
var result = collection.FindSync(filter).ToList();
```

Thanks to Mr.Saleem. Please refer to below link for more details.
[How to implement MongoDB nested $elemMatch Query in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35506660/how-to-implement-mongodb-elemmatch-query-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware about your context - so get this as a try to help you.
Be aware that contact is a list instead of array
That will help you to build own filter expressions

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;

    using MongoDB.Driver;

    /// <summary>
    /// The class 1.
    /// </summary>
    public class Class1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The get data.
        /// </summary>
        public async void GetData()
        {
            var context = new Context();
            var searchString = "1234";
            Expression<Func<SomeThing, bool>> filter = x =>
            x.Contact.Exists(s => s.FirstName == searchString
            && x.Contact.Exists(l=>l.LastName == searchString));
            var result = await context.SomeThingCollection.FindAsync(filter);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The context.
    /// </summary>
    public class Context
    {
        public const string CONNECTION_STRING_NAME = " ";
        public const string DATABASE_NAME = " ";
        public const string COLLECTION_NAME = "name";
        private static readonly IMongoClient _client;
        private static readonly IMongoDatabase _database;
        static Context()
        {
            var connectionString = "connectionString";
            _client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            _database = _client.GetDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
        }
        public IMongoCollection<SomeThing> SomeThingCollection
        {
            get
            {
                return _database.GetCollection<SomeThing>(COLLECTION_NAME);
            }
        }
    }

    public class SomeThing
    {
        public List<Contact> Contact { get; set; }
    }

    public class Contact
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Professor. That was helpful. But in my scenario, the above code is not working due the list of arrays in json format. eg: contact : [ [ {} ],[ {} ] ]