# How to deserialize query with LUUID value to BsonDocument

Tags: c#, mongodb, bsondocument

I'm trying to deserialize filter with LUUID (or NUUID in this example) to BsonDocument:

```
var tmpQry = "{'ValueId': NUUID('ca7ac84f-18bf-42f0-b028-333ed144c549')";
var tmpBson = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(tmpQry);
```

and getting an error:

```
System.FormatException: 'JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'NUUID'.'
```

I understand, that LUUID is not valid for JSON, but is it somehow possible to get BsonDocument from my string?

In my particular case i can't implement MongoDB nested $elemMatch query, like in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35506660/how-to-implement-mongodb-nested-elemmatch-query-in-c-sharp).
But my query contains identifiers:

```
db.getCollection('my_db').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            'Event.key_attributes': {
                $all: [
                    { '$elemMatch': { 'Type.Code': 'code1', 'ValueId': LUUID('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001') } },
                    { '$elemMatch': { 'Type.Code': 'code2', 'ValueId': LUUID("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002") } },
                    { '$elemMatch': { 'Type.Code': 'code3', 'ValueId': LUUID("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003") } }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            '_id': '$$CURRENT.Event.type._id',
            'code': { '$last': '$$CURRENT.Event.type.Code' },
            'value': { '$sum': '$$CURRENT.Event.value' }
        }
    }
]);
```

, and I even can't deserialize it into a BsonDocument.
Does my problem have any solution?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: the c# mongodb deserializer doesn't support LUUID. you would either have to convert your guids in the db to strings, or use ObjectIds instead.

Comment: @ĐĵΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ, could you explain in more detail about ObjectIds?

Comment: if the value of 'ValueId' was of type ObjectId, then the serializer can parse it properly. ex: var tmpQry = "{'ValueId': ObjectId('xxxxxxxxxxxxx')". basically get rid of guids altogether in the db.

Comment: @ĐĵΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ, this solution is just what I needed, thank you very much!

Comment: you're welcome. also if you wanna couple raw mongo queries to c# models, this can come in handy: https://dev.to/djnitehawk/overcoming-the-limitations-of-mongodb-c-driver-1110

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved this issue. Instead of trying to serialize the query from a string, I created BsonDocument pipeline:

```
var filter = new BsonDocument {{
    "$match", new BsonDocument {{
        "Event.key_attributes", new BsonDocument {{
        "$all", new BsonArray().AddRange(limit.KeyAttributes.Select(ka => new BsonDocument(
            "$elemMatch", new BsonDocument().AddRange(new List<BsonElement>{
            new BsonElement("Type.Code", ka.Type.Code),
            new BsonElement("ValueId", ka.ValueId)
            })
        )).ToList())
        }}
    }}
}};


var group = new BsonDocument {{
    "$group", new BsonDocument().AddRange(new List<BsonElement>{
        new BsonElement("_id", "$$CURRENT.Event.type._id"),
        new BsonElement("code", new BsonDocument{{
            "$last", "$$CURRENT.Event.type.Code" }}),
        new BsonElement("value", new BsonDocument{{
            "$sum", "$$CURRENT.Event.value" }})
    })
}};

var pipeline = new BsonDocument[]
{
    filter,
    group
};

var result = collection.Aggregate<MyOutputClass>(pipeline).ToListAsync();
```

There were no problems with Guid.

Answer (score 0):

The poster has worked around his problem, but for those happening up this question later: Use `CSUUID('guid-string-here')` for the CSharp legacy format.